# Gradle sync failed: invalid type code: 6C

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I created a new empty activity and this happens, Nothing exists on error 6C

I created 3 new projects all have this issue, I have the latest SDK and Android Studio with Q API

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please share your error or log completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i fixed it, some Experimental option was enabled called "Only Sync the Active Variant" under the File -> Setting -> Experimental -> Gradle that was preventing the fist time gradle building to happen